# error when using the function linkage in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got the following error when use linkage in matlab.

> Error: File: linkage.m Line: 6 Column: 4 "size" previously appeared to
>   be used as a function or command, conflicting with its use here as the
>   name of a variable.
>       A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or
>   eval.

Could someone help me with it?

Comment: Read the message - you almost certainly made a variable called `size`, so now the namespace is messed up, and you can't reach the function with the same name.

Comment: It looks like you named a variable `size`, which is a bad idea since a built-in function has this name. Try changing the variable's name and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, guys, for your time and attention. So, the error message told me that I made a variable called size in the file linkage.m? But the linkage.m is a default matlab function...

Comment: Moreover, in Line 6, column 4 of the linkage.m, that are simply comments there. Can anyone help ?

Comment: What is your input to `linkage`?

Comment: linkage(D_all, weighted). Here D_all is the vector representation of the distance matrix returned by the seqpdist function in matlab.

Comment: What is your input parameter values to `linkage`?

Comment: what do you mean by input parameter values? I thought I already explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linkage.m uses the matlab built-in function named size() but you have used the name size as a variable in your own code and thus then linkage.m tries to call the function size, it can't find it. Try finding that variable name and rename it to something else.